# Email Blast HTML Sizing Issues

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-email, mail-server

So I have an email blast that I was building and am fairly new to HTML specific email blasts, I have the images and links working properly but my problem is when viewing the blast on a phone the media query I tried to embed isn't working.

I'm using ASP.NET, and HTML to execute the blast. But I'm afraid I might have included too much css or not enough for the sizing of the body based on screen.

I'd appreciate if anyone could review my the code and see where I may have gone wrong.

```
     Dim emailmess As New MailMessage()
            emailmess.From = New MailAddress("example@example.com")
            emailmess.To.Add(New MailAddress("example@example.com"))
            emailmess.IsBodyHtml = True
            emailmess.Subject = "Aures Email Blast Test"
            emailmess.Body = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>@media screen and (max-width:600px){table[class='container-table'] {width: 100% !important;}}</style></head><body margin='0' padding='0'><table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='max-width: 600px; width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 800px;' background='http://www.becub3d.com/Aures_Eblast_F.png'><tr><td><table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='margin-top:107%; max-width:600px; height:9%; width:100%;' ><tr><td align='left' style='width:42px;'></td><td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' ><a href='https://www.aures.com/en/Contact/main-aures-contact' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td style='width:20px;'></td><td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' ><a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en_LPS_gfXY' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td style='width:20px;'></td><td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' ><a href='https://www.aures.com/en/point-of-sale-equipment-solutions-systems/yuno-touchscreen-terminal-multi-configuration' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td style='width:37px;'></td></tr></table><table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='30'><tr><td></td></tr></table><table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='10' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td style='width:440px;'></td><td style='width:75px;cursor:pointer;' ><a href='www.auresusa.com' style='display:block; text-decoration:none;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td></td></tr></table><table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='16'><tr><td style='width:290px;'></td><td style='width:15px;cursor:pointer;' ><a href='https://www.linkedin.com/company/aures-technologies-inc' style='display:block; text-decoration:none;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>"
            Dim thesmtp As New SmtpClient("webmail.example.com")
            thesmtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@example.com", "password")
            thesmtp.Port = 25
            thesmtp.EnableSsl = False
            thesmtp.Send(emailmess)
```

### HTML STRING BROKEN DOWN BELOW

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>@media screen and (max-width:600px){table[class='container-table'] {width: 100% !important;}}</style>
</head>
<body margin='0' padding='0'>
    <table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='max-width: 600px; width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 800px;' background='http://www.becub3d.com/Aures_Eblast_F.png'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='margin-top:107%; max-width:600px; height:9%; width:100%;' >
                    <tr>
                        <td align='left' style='width:42px;'></td>
                        <td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' >
                            <a href='https://www.aures.com/en/Contact/main-aures-contact' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                        <td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' >
                            <a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en_LPS_gfXY' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td style='width:20px;'></td>
                        <td style='width:100px;cursor:pointer;' >
                            <a href='https://www.aures.com/en/point-of-sale-equipment-solutions-systems/yuno-touchscreen-terminal-multi-configuration' style='display:block; text-decoration:none; height:70px;'>&nbsp;</a></td><td style='width:37px;'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='30'>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='10' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:440px;'></td>
                        <td style='width:75px;cursor:pointer;' >
                            <a href='www.auresusa.com' style='display:block; text-decoration:none;'>&nbsp;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' height='16'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width:290px;'></td>
                        <td style='width:15px;cursor:pointer;' >
                            <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/company/aures-technologies-inc' style='display:block; text-decoration:none;'>&nbsp;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I had a look at your HTML as well and it seems there are a few errors in the HTML. If you look at the `HTML STRING BROKEN DOWN BELOW` in a HTML editor and look for the lines 9 and 30 you will find doubling up of cellpadding and cellspacing.

As Gwally said, coding email is not like web, you CSS has to be inline and images are supposed to be in the HTML. I wouldn't recommend a fully image based email as it can cause delivery issues in different EPS's. If you do want to send image based email then slice it up into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over your code and I am basing my answer using this code as an example:

`<table class='container-table' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='max-width: 600px; width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 800px;' background='http://www.becub3d.com/Aures_Eblast_F.png'>`

You are using images in the background of tables. The background images will not resize, just the table. The image usually remains the same size.

This will also ensure your images do not show up in Outlook, which does not support background images. This is why it looks terrible on IOS devices, and not not display on Android.

HTML for email is not the same as Web development. It uses a much smaller CSS code base than HTML 5 development. It doesn't support the same code everywhere the way you see with modern browsers. In fact, the rendering engine for Microsoft Outlook is based on Word. You should check out the Campaign Monitor CSS compliance table:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

I might suggest you look up a working html responsive email template, study how it's working with images and go from there. I'd suggest something like Zurb Foundation for Emails:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Good luck.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a more acceptable place for the image to be used and still be responsive. Is it better to be placed in the body instead as the bg image. Or perhaps a DIV instead of using a table as the initial holder?

Thanks for the links, looking into them now